# How to get a column length defined in the table schema in teradata

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I need to find difference between length of a column value with column length defined while creating table.

Ex: I have a table schema as below.

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

with values

```
id  name    subject 
1   Alex    maths   
2   Bob     maths   
3   Clark   science 
4   Dave    maths
```

Now I need the output as

```
id  name    subject len(name) remain_space 
1   Alex    maths    4           6
2   Bob     maths    3           7
3   Clark   science  5           5
4   Dave    maths    4           6
```

Here the remain space is calculated using the formula **(10 - len(name))** ,where 10 is the max.length of the column 'name' defined while creating table. How do I achieve this in Teradata?

Comment: What value does this have that could justify the effort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Standard SQL function to get the length of a string is named `Char_Length`:

```
10 - Char_Length(name)
```

If you don't want to hardcode the defined VarChar length:

```
RegExp_Substr(TYPE(name), '[0-9]+') - Char_Length(name)
```

Comment: Char_length (v) give the actual length of a string not the total length defined for that column

Comment: @Sivachandran: Exactly, that's what you were asking for: *the remain space is calculated using the formula (10 - len(name)) ,where 10 is the max.length of the column 'name' defined while creating table*

Comment: I need the value 10 should be passed dynamically - this value should be taken from the schema. May be my communication interuppted wrongly, sorry for that. Also, I tried the Regexp_substr() - it shows some syntax error.